# CallKit integtaion in my voip app

Tags: ios, callkit

I want to get details regarding block calls and identification using `callkit framework`.
Is there anyone has done such work?
I have started little bit with

```
CXProviderConfiguration * configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"Bitcall"];
    CXProvider *callkitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration: configuration];
    [callkitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];
    CXCallUpdate *update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    update.localizedCallerName = @"Ravadam Patel";
    [callkitProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:[NSUUID UUID]  update:update completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

But not getting exact detail which I want.